# Regex to find 9 to 11 digit integer occuring anywhere closest to a keyword

Tags: regex, oracle

In simple term, what I am looking for is this If there is a string, which has a keyword `ZTFN00`, then the regex shall be able to return the closest 9 to 11 digit number to the left or right side of the string.

I want to do this in REGEXP_REPLACE function of oracle.

Below are some of the sample strings:

```
The following error occurred in the SAP UPDATE_BP service as part of the combine: 

(error:653, R11:186:Number 867278489 Already Exists for ID Type ZTFN00)
```

Expected result: `867278489`

```
The following error occurred in the SAP UPDATE_BP service as part of the combine

(error:653, R11:186:Number ZTFN00 identification number 123456778 already exist)
```

Expected result: `123456778`

Comment: What should happen if there are numbers on both side of ZTFN00?

Comment: Good question ! It should return the closest match. However we are not considering that scenario

Comment: From what I can gather from the docs, Oracle has poor regex support, nowhere close to PCRE - I'm removing that tag before someone assumes he can use fancy regex operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to easily do this with regular expressions, but if you want to do the task without PL/SQL, you can do something like the following.

It's a little bit tricky, combining many calls to regexp functions to evaluate, for each occurrence of digit string, the distance from your keyword and then pick the nearest one.

```
with test(string, keyWord) as 
( select
'(error:653, R11:186: 999999999 Number 0000000000 Already Exists for ID Type ZTFN00  hjhk  11111111111 kjh k222222222)',
'ZTFN00'
from dual)
select numberString
from (
    select numberString, 
           decode (greatest (numberPosition, keyWordPosition),
                      keyWordPosition,
                        keyWordPosition - numberPosition - numberLength,
                      numberPosition,
                        numberPosition - keyWordPosition - keyWordLength
                  ) as distance
    from (
            select regexp_instr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) as numberPosition,
                   instr( string, keyWord) as keyWordPosition,
                   length(regexp_substr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level)) as numberLength,
                   regexp_substr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) as numberString,
                   length(keyWord) as keyWordLength
            from test
            connect by regexp_instr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) != 0
         )
    order by distance
)where rownum = 1
```

Looking at the single parts:

```
SQL> with test(string, keyWord) as
  2  ( select
  3  '(error:653, R11:186: 999999999 Number 0000000000 Already Exists for ID Type ZTFN00  hjhk  11111111111 kjh k222222222)',
  4  'ZTFN00'
  5  from dual)
  6              select regexp_instr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) as numberPosition,
  7                     instr( string, keyWord) as keyWordPosition,
  8                     length(regexp_substr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level)) as numberLength,
  9                     regexp_substr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) as numberString,
 10                     length(keyWord) as keyWordLength
 11              from test
 12              connect by regexp_instr(string, '[0-9]{9,11}', 1, level) != 0;

NUMBERPOSITION KEYWORDPOSITION NUMBERLENGTH NUMBERSTRING     KEYWORDLENGTH
-------------- --------------- ------------ ---------------- -------------
            22              77            9 999999999                    6
            39              77           10 0000000000                   6
            91              77           11 11111111111                  6
           108              77            9 222222222                    6
```

This scans all the string, and iterates while `insrt (...) != 0`, that is while there are occurrences; the `level` is used to look for the first, second, ... occurrence, so that row 1 gives the first occurrence, row two the second and so on, while exists the nth occurrence.

This part is only used to evaluate some useful fields, tha we use to look both to the right and to the left of you keyword, exactly evaluating the distance between the string number and the keyword:

```
select numberString, 
           decode (greatest (numberPosition, keyWordPosition),
                      keyWordPosition,
                        keyWordPosition - numberPosition - numberLength,
                      numberPosition,
                        numberPosition - keyWordPosition - keyWordLength
                  ) as distance
```

The inner query is ordered by distance, so that the first row contains the nearest string; that's why in the outermost query we only extract the row with 
`rownum = 1` to get the nearest row.
It can be re-written in a more compact way, but this is a bit more readable.

This should even work when you have multiple occurrences of the digit string, even on both sides of your keyword.

Comment: good solution ! May I request a bit of help in understanding the

 connect by regexp_instr(string, '[0-9]{8,11}', 1, level) != 0 . Speficially, the "level" part and the use of rownum=1 at the end of the whole sql

Comment: Beautiful ! 
If I try to generalize this query using a table in place of "select * from dual" like

with test(string, keyWord) as
  ( select string,'ZTFN00' from mytable )

Where mytable as 9 similar strings to be evaluated

Then also it outputs only 1 row in place of 9 rows. Can you kindly advise, how can we correct this, please

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for me in RegexBuddy with Oracle mode selected (10g, 11g and 12c):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycolumn, 
    '\(error:[0-9]+,[ ]+
    (
      (
        ([0-9]{9,11})()
      |
        ZTFN00()
      |
        [^ ),]+
      )
      [ ),]+
    )+
    \4\5', 
    1, 1, 'cx', 3) FROM mytable;
```

The regex treats the main body of the string as a series of tokens matching the general pattern `[^ ),]+` (*one or more of any characters except space, right parenthesis, or comma*).  But there are two specific tokens that it tries to match first: the keyword (`ZTFN00`) and a valid ID number (`[0-9]{9,11}`).

The empty groups at the end of the first two alternatives serve as check boxes; the corresponding backreferences at the end (`\4` and `\5`) will only succeed if those groups participated in the match, meaning both an ID number and the keyword were seen.

(This is an obscure "feature" that definitely doesn't work in many flavors, so I can't be positive it will work in Oracle.  Please let me know if it doesn't.)

The ID number is captured in group #3, and that's what the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` command returns.  (Since you only want to retrieve the number, there no call for `REGEXP_REPLACE`.)

Comment: This one is good but when I run the same with below string, it returns null

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('The following error occurred in the SAP_COMBINE_BP service as part of the combine (error:655, R11:330:Identification type ZTFN00, identification number 76796162 not available in BP 123456)', 
    '\(error:653,[ ]
    (
      (
        ([[:digit:]]{8,11})()
      |
        ZTFN00()
      |
        [^[:space:])]+
      )
      [ )]
    )+
    \4\5', 
    1, 1, 'cx', 3) from dual

May I request help for a step by step understanding of the regex please

Comment: Your new sample string has a different error number (655), a comma after the keyword, and an ID number that's only eight digits long (meaning it shouldn't match in any case).  I'll update the regex to account for the new variations, and add more explanation.